# Error starting an activity using a Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I have been doing a Custom ListView and I want to open another class when I click on some element on the ListView.

So I started an Adapter,class, activity and its .xml files.

Class:

```
public class DatosMercado {
protected Drawable foto;
protected String titulo;
protected String info;
protected long id;

public DatosMercado(Drawable foto, String titulo, String info){
    this.foto = foto;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.info = info;


}

public Drawable getFoto(){
    return foto;
}

public void setFoto(Drawable foto){
    this.foto = foto;
}
public String getTitulo(){
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo){
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getInfo(){
    return info;
}

public void setInfo(String info){
    this.info = info;
}

public long getId(){
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id){
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Adapter:

```
public class AdapterDatosMercado extends BaseAdapter {

protected Activity activity;
//Asignamos la clase DatosMercado al arrayadapter
protected ArrayList<DatosMercado> items;

//Metodo constructor de la clase
public AdapterDatosMercado(Activity activity, ArrayList<DatosMercado> items){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.items = items;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return items.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    //Asociar el Layout de la lista que hemos creado
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inf.inflate(R.layout.mercado2, null);
    }
    //Creamos un objeto de la clase DatosMercado
    DatosMercado datos = items.get(position);
    //Relleno la foto
    ImageView foto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.Photo);
    foto.setImageDrawable(datos.getFoto());
    //Rellenamos el nombre
    TextView titulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Title);
    titulo.setText(datos.getTitulo());
    //Rellenamos la informacion
    TextView info = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Description);
    info.setText(datos.getInfo());

    //retornamos la vista
    return v;
}
```

}

And I have a problem on the activity, if I exectue that code an error says:

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.upc.com.game/edu.upc.com.game.Mercado}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Here is my code:

```
public class Mercado extends ListActivity  {

String classnames[] = {"BuscarColtan"};
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mercado);

    ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listamoviles);
    ArrayList<DatosMercado> arraydatos = new ArrayList<DatosMercado>();
    DatosMercado datos;

    //Datos introducidos

    datos = new DatosMercado(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ipear), "IPear", "La mejor marca del mundo");
    arraydatos.add(datos);
    datos = new DatosMercado(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ipear), "Bensung", "Moviles Star de alta gama");
    arraydatos.add(datos);
    datos = new DatosMercado(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ipear), "HiYou", "Venimos desde China a dar el salto al mercado europeo");
    arraydatos.add(datos);
    datos = new DatosMercado(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ipear), "IQ", "Moviles de alta tecnologia a bajo coste");
    arraydatos.add(datos);
    datos = new DatosMercado(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ipear), "Zonya", "No te resistiras a comprar nuestros Hesperia");
    arraydatos.add(datos);
    datos = new DatosMercado(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ipear), "Hullaguey", "Los mobiles mas baratos");
    arraydatos.add(datos);


    //Crear el Adapter personalizado
    AdapterDatosMercado adapter = new AdapterDatosMercado(this,arraydatos);

    //Aplicarlo
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);




}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(lv,v,position,id);
    String openClass = classnames[position];
    try {
        Class selected = Class.forName("edu.upc.com.game. "+ openClass);
        Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this,selected);
        startActivity(selectedIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The original name of the ListView is:

```
android:id="@+id/listamoviles"
```

I changed it to:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

But now I have a problem with that Line:

```
ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listamoviles);
```

I have to define that list view cause if I don't do that it doesn't work. The application works if I delete the onListItemClick and I change the ListActivity to an Activity but I want to open another activity (class) by doing click on the customed listview.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you extends by `ListActivity`
then remove this line

```
 ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listamoviles);
```

also replace

```
  lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

by

```
  setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It keeps failing, because the problem is that if I change the name to `android:id="@android:id/list"` the line: `ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listamoviles);` it doesnt work and i have to change the name of listamoviles, but I can't put /list like a name.